# Deserialise a Kraken JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, kraken.com

I used to be loading data from Cryptocompare's API.
This post got me what I wanted for Cryptocompare.

[Parsing Cryptocompare API Json data in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134388/parsing-cryptocompare-api-json-data-in-c-sharp)

However, I notice that this API is not bulletproof, it's not always returning an answer. So I want to use Kraken itself.

Now I am trying to deserialise the new JSON but this is not straightforward as Cryptocompare's JSON.

Here is an example JSON:

https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=ETHUSD&interval=30

```
{"error":[],"result":{"XETHZUSD":[[1519236000,"825.94","846.00","825.94","845.00","835.62","858.29381033",708],[1519237800,"846.00","848.84","835.55","836.00","844.31","647.42747317",731],[1519239600,"836.00","841.09","830.76","834.89","835.13","1051.44905097",609],[1520530200,"706.24","710.43","701.90","704.59","707.70","1763.41692283",459]],"last":1520528400}}
```

I have not been able to deserialise this JSON.

Solved!!!

final solution:

```
    var Results_Exchange_Kraken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataRoot_Kraken>(Content_Exchange_Kraken);


    var price_data_kraken = Results_Exchange_Kraken.result.XETHZUSD;


    public class Kraken_Result
    {
        public List<List<object>> XETHZUSD { get; set; }
        public int last { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataRoot_Kraken
    {
        public List<object> error { get; set; }
        public Kraken_Result result { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you! I'll bookmark the URL.

Comment: "I have not been able to deserialise this JSON.", and I don't even see an attempt from your side. Please read [ask] and either try for yourself or post what you have. Also, make it easier for us and run the JSON through a prettifier

Comment: Have you tried creating a model and then simply deserializing your JSON into the object of that model?

Comment: @camilo what i have does not work and might the the 20th attempt. I am not here to show what I have attempted (it was a LOT), this is not a school project, I am here to ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Model to de-serialise your data

```
public class Result
{
    public List<List<object>> XETHZUSD { get; set; }
    public int last { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> error { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

Model Generated by [Model Generator](http://json2csharp.com/)

Then use [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for c# to de-serialise your data

E.g.

```
RootObject tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("JSON String here");
```

final solution:

```
    var Results_Exchange_Kraken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataRoot_Kraken>(Content_Exchange_Kraken);


    var price_data_kraken = Results_Exchange_Kraken.result.XETHZUSD;


    public class Kraken_Result
    {
        public List<List<object>> XETHZUSD { get; set; }
        public int last { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataRoot_Kraken
    {
        public List<object> error { get; set; }
        public Kraken_Result result { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Yea i know. saves a lot of time.

Comment: `List<List<object>>`? `List<object>`? What a horrible use of generics

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i didn't write it brother i mentioned that is something model generator gives you.

Comment: @Yeahson Glad it helped you.Please Accept answer if it was helpful

Comment: json2csharp takes some pretty bad guesses at data types. It should rarely be blindly pasted into code.

Comment: This doesn't deserialize the underlying array. You'll find it's "null"!